# VF Error: When accessing certain properties of a field set

Tags: visualforce, repeat

I have a VF page in which I have an `<apex:repeat>` tag:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!seHandoffFields}" var="field">
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText="{!$ObjectType.DealQualificationSurvey__c.fields[field].inlineHelpText}">
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!field.label}" />
        <apex:outputPanel >
            <apex:inputField value="{!surveyHeader[field]}" rendered="{!surveyHeader.Status__c != 'Completed'}" 
                required='{!field.required}'/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!surveyHeader[field]}" rendered="{!surveyHeader.Status__c = 'Completed'}" />
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:repeat>
```

`seHandoffFields` is a `List<Schema.FieldSetmember>` for a given field set.

When I have `{!field.required}` in the code, I get the following error when deploying:

> force-app\main\default\pages\DealQualificationSurvey.page  Cannot coerce 'core.apexpages.el.adapters.RuntimeTypeMetadataELAdapter@6a6c598f' of class core.apexpages.el.adapters.RuntimeTypeMetadataELAdapter to class java.lang.Boolean (incompatible type)

Here's the kicker, I'm doing the EXACT same thing somewhere else in the Visualforce page and I do not get the error. I only get the error when trying to add it a second time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the issue is that I am using `field` as a variable name in more then 1 repeat tag on the page. Changing the name of `field` to `seField` resolved the error.

**Note:** These tags are not nested. They are not even siblings. They are third cousins at best.

**Note 2:** This error only happens with some attributes. If I remove the required attribute, the code works perfectly fine (no issues with `field.label`). I also noticed a different error when trying to use `field.fieldPath`

**Note 3:** Api versions tested are 44, 45, and 46.

Comment: this would have driven me nuts trying to find -- kudos

Comment: You should not use the same variable name more than once in a page, or you risk all kinds of bugs. Sometimes it works okay, other times not.